# How to get a full working typewriter effect including text disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a typewriter effect, and got that working, but I'm really struggling to make the letters dissapear one for one again. This is the code that I'm using

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(typeWriter, 500);
});

var i = 0;
var txt = 'My name is Bram Surname';
var speed = 50;
let typewriterDone = false

function typeWriter() {


  if (i < txt.length && typewriterDone == false) {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
 

    if (i == txt.length) {
      typewriterDone = true
    }

  } else {
    typewriterDone = true;

    // remove 1 letter like first one

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

Comment: What are you struggling with? How to remove a letter from the beginning or end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove each letter again one by one, immediately after you've added them all? If so, then this will do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(typeWriter, 500);
});

var i = 0;
var txt = 'My name is Bram Surname';
var speed = 50;
let direction = 1;

function typeWriter() {

  var title = document.getElementById("title");

  if (i < txt.length && direction == 1) {
    title.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
  } else {
    if (i == txt.length) direction = 2;
    if (i != 0) {
      title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight reworking of your approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(() => typeOn(document.getElementById("title"), 'My name is Bram Surname'), 500);
});

const speed = 50;

// convenience function for adding a character
const addChar = (elem, char) => elem.innerHTML += char;

// convenience function for removing a character
const removeChar = elem => elem.innerText = elem.innerText.substr(1);

// type on the given string
function typeOn(elem, str) {
  const [first, ...remaining] = str;
  addChar(elem, first);
  if (remaining.length) {
    setTimeout(() => typeOn(elem, remaining), speed);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(() => typeOff(elem), speed);
  }
}

// remove the string, one char at a time
function typeOff(elem) {
  removeChar(elem);
  if (elem.innerText.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => typeOff(elem), speed);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a vanilla implementation at: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/YzXLJGa (see also snippet below).

The thing is to split all the content into an array and then append them one by one with a timeout to the title. After the title length matches with the original content, it can be considered as completed and then start removing the text with same interval.

```js
const typewriter = (content, interval = 100) => {
  const title = document.querySelector("#title");
  const splitContent = content.split("");
  const handleContent = newContent => {
    if (newContent.length) {
      title.textContent += newContent;

      if (title.textContent === content) {
        window.setTimeout(handleContent, interval, "");
      }
    } else {
      title.textContent = title.textContent.substr(1);

      if (title.textContent.length) {
        window.setTimeout(handleContent, interval, "");
      }
    }
  };

  splitContent.forEach((letter, i, arr) => {
    window.setTimeout(handleContent, i * interval, letter);
  });
};

typewriter("My name is Bram Surname");
```

```html
<h1 id='title'></h1>
```